# Collecting elements in a list while iterating a collection in a thread-safe way

Tags: salesforce, mule, java.util.concurrent

I set Salesforce fetchSize=100 but it does not fetch elements in sets of 100 for my query. Therefore I want to be able to collect the single result from the ConsumerIterator into a list, to be handed off to a batch process in sets of 100. Here is the code below. Is this a correct way to do it?  I would appreciate any suggestions on how to do it correctly. I would like to process all the ConsumerIterator elements in batches of 50. If the batch is less than 50, I would like to process that batch. My attempt is below

```
  ConsumerIterator<HashMap<String,Object>> iter=
                    (ConsumerIterator<HashMap<String,Object>>)obj;
  List<HashMap<String,Object>> l=new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
  while(iter.hasNext()){
   Object payload=iter.next();
  if(l.size()<50){
        l.add((HashMap<String,Object>)payload);
  }else{
    write(l);
  } 

  public int [] write(List<HashMap<String,Object> list)
  {
    synchronized(list)
    {
      ArrayList newList=copy(list);
      save(newList);
    }
```

+

Comment: In the code as posted, `l` is not seen by any other thread, so neither, using a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` nor using `synchronized(list)` is really needed.  In contrast, we can’t see from your code snippet, whether `obj` or its underlying data source is shared between threads, so it is impossible to say whether iterating it that way is correct. Besides that, you are mixing generic types, raw types, and unnecessary dropping of type information by assigning an item with known type to `Object`, followed by an avoidable unchecked cast. You should clean up that code…

Answer (score 0):

In Salesforce query, you can append "Limit 100;" at the end of the query to get only 100 elements in a list.

Comment: Limit will only bring 100 elements. I have set a fetchSize=100 which will return all the data but in pages of 100. The problem is that the ConsumerIterator only returns the elements one by one which requires me to collect them in a list. What I'm asking is how to collect these elements efficiently and correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using a fetch size of 100 and then used the resulting ConsumerIterator to aggregate the elements.